# jQuery exclude first, second and last table row

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am excluding first and last table row to calculate summary. Now added one more header with merging. So I need to skip second row as well. So I need to skip

first, second and last. I have added tr:not(:first,second, last) but It is not working. May I know how can I skip second row of table in this script.

Thanks,

```js
$(".printer-type tr:not(:first, last) td:last-child").text(function() {
  var totalVal = 0;
  $(this).prevAll().each(function() {
    totalVal += parseFloat($(this).children('.txtfld').val()) || 0;
    //totalVal += parseInt( );
  });
  return parseFloat(totalVal).toFixed(1);
});
```

Comment: There's no `:second` selector, use `:eq(1)`

Comment: It would probably be better design to assign classes to rows, rather than selecting them by position.

Comment: How about $(".printer-type").not(':first').not(':first').not(':last'), although there should be a shorter representation of this.

Comment: $(".printer-type").not(':first').not(':first').not(':last') also working. Thanks Riddler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`:lt(index)`](https://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/)

> Select all elements at an `index` less than index within the matched set.

```
$(".printer-type tr:not(:lt(2), :last) td:last-child")
```

[`:gt(index)`](https://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) can also be used

> Select all elements at an `index` greater than index within the matched set.

```
$(".printer-type tr:gt(1):not(:last) td:last-child")
```

Comment: It should be `:lt(2)`

Answer (score 1):

Can use [`slice()`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) instead of selectors

```
$('.printer-type tr').slice(1,-1).children(':last-child')
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/s844ka1L/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

[:last](https://api.jquery.com/last/) for last item , and [:eq](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)(index) for second